# "repair" root PK using recursive self joins

Tags: sql, db2

Take the following fictional website data (0 specifies a missing value):

| USER_ID | TRANSACTION_ID_PARENT | TRANSACTION_ID_CHILD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 0 | 11 |
| 1 | 11 | 12 |

How do I add a column that "repairs"/generates a root primary key:

| USER_ID | TRANSACTION_ID_PARENT | TRANSACTION_ID_CHILD | TRANSACTION_ID_ROOT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 11 | 11 |
| 1 | 11 | 12 | 11 |

My hunch would be a recursive CTE grouped by USER_ID? How to achieve this in the IBM db2 dialect?

Maybe there are more elegant database specific variants of a recursive self join?

Comment: To me all nodes have root zero (`0`).

Comment: Sorry, 0 here specifies a missing value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done this way :

```
with table1 (USER_ID, TRANSACTION_ID_PARENT, TRANSACTION_ID_CHILD) as (
  VALUES
  (1, 0, 1),
  (1, 1, 2),
  (1, 2, 3),
  (1, 0, 11),
  (1, 11, 12)
),
rec (USER_ID, TRANSACTION_ID_PARENT, TRANSACTION_ID_CHILD, TRANSACTION_ID_ROOT) as (
  select USER_ID, TRANSACTION_ID_PARENT, TRANSACTION_ID_CHILD, TRANSACTION_ID_CHILD
  from table1 where TRANSACTION_ID_PARENT= 0
  union all
  select rec.USER_ID, table1.TRANSACTION_ID_PARENT, table1.TRANSACTION_ID_CHILD, rec.TRANSACTION_ID_ROOT
  from rec, table1 where (rec.user_id, rec.TRANSACTION_ID_CHILD) = (table1.USER_ID, table1.TRANSACTION_ID_PARENT)
)
select * from rec
order by USER_ID, TRANSACTION_ID_ROOT, TRANSACTION_ID_PARENT, TRANSACTION_ID_CHILD
```

| USER_ID | TRANSACTION_ID_PARENT | TRANSACTION_ID_CHILD | TRANSACTION_ID_ROOT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 11 | 11 |
| 1 | 11 | 12 | 11 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XWidQk9R)